# Mysql append <p></p>

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am looking for a way to work my way through a particular column within a table to add a `<p>` at the beginning of the entry and `</p>` at the end.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Do you want to update the column of that table or it needed while fetching result?

Comment: It sounds like you're creating an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: An HTML table or a database table?

Comment: Reference: [MySQL manual: string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mySQL statement is easy using [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = CONCAT("<p>", columnname, "</p>");
```

Think about whether this really makes sense, though: Do you really need this data inside the table? Why not simply append it when outputting the data in your web interface (or whatever)?

Comment: +1 for suggesting to drop HTML from SQL table, it's gross at the very least!